# Show individual lines of text sequentially from the textView in android

Tags: android-animation

i'm creating a transition for a text view in android. onswipe the current textView is moved and the next textview is shown,with a bounce animation.

i'm presently getting the entire textView at once, rather i require the text to appear line after line. Similar to how is happens in MS powerpoint, where very bullet points appear one after the other.

Can anyone pls tell how this can be done ?

Regards,
Vasudev

Answer (score 0):

Use a Vertical LinearLayout that contains a textview for each line of text

Use `AnimationFactory` which has a function `inFromLeft` that you can use before `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` of each textview to animate them.